# Print dictionary rotation result in vertical columns

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
dict1 = {'Name': ['Mary','Bob'],'Surname': ['White','Red']}
```

If I do the print I have this output:

```
Surname    White
           Red
Name       Mary
           Bob
```

but I would like this output

```
Name       Surname
Mary       White
Bob        Red
```

How can I do it without using pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that will sort keys of your dict (so you will get same out every time for same data) and print your dict in format you supplied with any amounts of keys and values of your dict.

```
dict1 = {'Name': ['Mary','Bob'],'Surname': ['White','Red']}
sorted_keys = sorted(dict1.keys())

spacing = 10
print_sheme = ('{:<' + str(spacing) + '}')*len(list(dict1.values())[0])

print(print_sheme.format(*sorted_keys))
for i in range(len(list(dict1.values())[0])):
    values_to_print = [dict1[key][i] for key in sorted_keys]
    print(print_sheme.format(*values_to_print))
```

Output:

```
Name      Surname   
Mary      White     
Bob       Red
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty straightforward implementation that handles arbitrary keys, uneven lists, and dynamically-sized columns:

```
def column_print(d, spacing=2):
    columns = [[x] + y for x, y in zip(d.keys(), d.values())]
    col_widths = [spacing + max([len(x) for x in e]) for e in columns]

    for i in range(max([len(x) for x in columns])):
        for w, col in zip(col_widths, columns):
            print((col[i] if i < len(col) else "").ljust(w), end="")
        print()

column_print({'Name': ['Mary','Bob','Mark'], 'Surname': ['White','Red','Blue','Black'], 'MI': ['S','A']})
```

Output:

```
Name  Surname  MI  
Mary  White    S   
Bob   Red      A   
Mark  Blue         
      Black
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/CyberOrangeredBoastmachine)

Answer (score 1):

A less general, but much shorter answer. Just iterate over both lists (but you can extend this to as how many lists you need to reference simultaneously):

```
print("{:10} {:10}".format("Name", "Surname"))
for (name, surname) in zip(dict1.get('Name'), dict1.get('Surname')):
    print("{:10} {:10}".format(name, surname))
```